# JavaScript for loop and for-in loop for fetched data from database

Tags: javascript, database, for-loop

```
var fetchResults = tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE sessions.dayid=1 ORDER BY sessions.starttime ASC", [],
        function(tx, data){
            processorFunc(data);
            var contxt = "";
            for (var numb = 0; numb < data.rows.length; numb++) {
                contxt += data.rows[numb].title + "=" + data.rows[numb].startTime + "=" + 
                        data.rows[numb].endtime + "=" + data.rows[numb].type + "\n";
            }
            console.log(contxt);
            contxt = "";
            for (var numb in data.rows) {
                contxt += data.rows[numb].title + "=" + data.rows[numb].startTime + "=" + 
                        data.rows[numb].endtime + "=" + data.rows[numb].type + "\n";
            }
            console.log(contxt);
        });
```

In console, I see that for-in loop returns two more lines and all elements are undefined. I use Web Sql API here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OUHC.png)

Does anybody know why this will happen?

Comment: Please put your code in your question as text instead of linking to a tiny screenshot.

Comment: How can I edit it? I don't see any button

Comment: It should be under your question’s tags.

Comment: The part of the linked answer that applies to your case here is likely *“In addition, if any monkey patches or shims are put into place on the array object, they can show up here.”*, and you can confirm that by logging `numb` each time around the loop.

Comment: got it, thanks, though don't fully understand :P

Comment: If you add a `console.log('Got a key:', numb);` inside your second loop, it’ll probably be clearer: some things that aren’t numbers should be logged.